# Knex migration timestamp not timestamping

Tags: knex.js

```
exports.up = async function(knex) {
  knex.schema.alterTable('posts', (t) => {
    t.timestamps(true, true)
  })
}

exports.down = async function(knex) {
  knex.schema.alterTable('posts', (t) => {
    t.dropTimestamps()
  })
}
```

According to the docs, this will create a `created_at` and `updated_at` columns.

But it does not.

How do you use Knex to create these columns.

Comment: How are you executing it?

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing your schema builder. Add await or return your schema builder from migration handler.

```
exports.up = async function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.alterTable('posts', (t) => {
    t.timestamps(true, true)
  })
}

exports.down = async function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.alterTable('posts', (t) => {
    t.dropTimestamps()
  })
}
```

Edit after @valem's comment

Code above is pretty much equivalent this, if async / await is not used:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return Promise.resolve(knex.schema.alterTable('posts', (t) => {
    t.timestamps(true, true);
  }));
}

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return Promise.resolve(knex.schema.alterTable('posts', (t) => {
    t.dropTimestamps();
  }));
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `await` keyword. Also, these don't need to be async functions. They should either return a promise or use async/await.

Comment: @valem No I didn't. They don't need to be async, but they should be (I've been knex  maintainer since 2015 or so). Setting them up as async functions makes them implicitly to always return a `Promise`.  So that async keyword causes returned schema builder (that is thenable) to be automatically resolved to a Promise. This is really the preferred way to write migrations in async / await era of Node.

Comment: oh i've been doing `function(knex) { return knex.schema ... }` . is that incorrect or is the knex method a promise?

Comment: Knex.schema is thenable. Thenables might work too, I don't remember that exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (works for me)

```
t.dropColumn('created_at');
t.dropColumn('updated_at');
```

instead of t.dropTimestamps();